# Program segment fault around std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource

Tags: memory-management, c++17

The program does nothing except farewell to the world:

```
/* Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC 10.1.0 and libstdc++-10-dev */

#include <memory_resource>
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

/* declare global memory resource */
std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource pool;

int main(int argv, char * argc[]){

    std::puts("Goodbye World!");

}
```

It compiles fine, but terminates with SEGV on

```
/usr/include/c++/10/memory_resource
```

line 445, in constructor of SPR:

```
synchronized_pool_resource()
: synchronized_pool_resource(pool_options(), get_default_resource())
```

> [Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] (Unknown Source:0)
> libstdc++.so.6!std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource::synchronized_pool_resource(std::pmr::pool_options const&, std::pmr::memory_resource*) (Unknown Source:0)
> std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource::synchronized_pool_resource(std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource * const this) (/usr/include/c++/10/memory_resource:445)
> __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int __initialize_p, int __priority) (/data/solution/projects/test/source/main.cpp:10)
> _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z4testRNSt3pmr26synchronized_pool_resourceE() (/data/solution/projects/test/source/main.cpp:16)
> __libc_csu_init (Unknown Source:0)
> libc.so.6!__libc_start_main(int (*)(int, char **, char **) main, int argc, char ** argv, int (*)(int, char **, char **) init, void (*)(void) fini, void (*)(void) rtld_fini, void * stack_end) (/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/libc-start.c:266)
> _start (Unknown Source:0)

The chain of calls on stack explains me that the program might have been linked to libstdc++.so.6. Is this a possible reason and if so, what shall I do?

I was using

> GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.2-0ubuntu1~18.04) 8.2

for debugging. Would it be because GDB is not ready for this?

BTW: I really wasn't capable of using this editor to past images. It just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-pthread` to your g++ linking call. I can't fault you if you think there should be a comprehensible error message…

Comment: However, -pthread option was present and not possible to be the root cause. On the other hand, if in code is there construction of a std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource, then everything goes just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this with Ubuntu 18.04 and g++-10 (10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) from the toolchain PPA on x86-64 if `-pthread` is present. Command line `g++-10 -o /tmp/pmr-gcc-10 -std=c++20 -pthread pmr-gcc-10.cxx`. You can run `ldd` on the binary to verify that `libpthread.so.0` is in fact used. (I also tried `-std=c++17`.)